Pycharm USINg 400gb virtual memory with 2048 heat size already
ok I've just started using PyCharm was frustrated with VsCode and PyCharm just pushes my CPU usage to 80%// BTW I use a MacBook Pro M3 Pro 18gb RAM. is it smth I'm doing wrong or like idk it shouldn't be using this much CPU like considering the M3 Pro chip
the heap size allocated is already 2048 mb and it's also using huge chunk of virtual memory - 400gb life is this surreal 400 gb??
restarting and like I just don't want my Mac to heat and not lag and work normally

Who cares about virtual memory? If the application doesn't actually try to use that memory, but is just allocating address space, it doesn't matter at all; it's not like we're still in a 32-bit world where you can realistically run out. Do you have a real, practical problem or is this question only based off being surprised by the metrics?

alr idk if virtual memory matters but yeah it is lagging there's a problem//like idk the issue but I felt the lag and got that info memory running out allocate more heap size so yeah pls I think you seem to know stuff pls help

If I were there in person I could dig in more -- make sure you're using a current release with native arm64 binaries f/e, to confirm that what you're seeing isn't Rosetta overhead -- but there aren't enough details in the question to allow a concrete diagnosis.
